Does chroma_location subsampling not matter with 4:2:0?
Did I get this right? In 4:2:0 the left half of the 4x2 rectangle has the same chroma anyway so it does not matter which chroma_location subsampling type is used?
ffmpeg7 seems to default to chroma_location=topleft i.e. Chroma Subsampling Type 2 with PAL .dv input:
0 left, 1 center, 2 topleft, 3 top, 4 bottomleft, 5 bottom, auto gives 2 with .dv input, blank unspecified.
On the other hand, with 4:1:1 input: isn't chroma_location topleft the same as top but other chroma_locations sample different chroma or pick a mean of two chromas, right?
PAL .dv seems to be 4:2:0 and NTSC .dv 4:1:1.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Figure-E2-Location-of-the-top-left-chroma-sample-when-chroma-format-idc-is-equal-to-1_fig1_327253648
For example, I have used the following command to convert 4:3 PAL .dv to .mp4. Setting chroma_location to any variation does not seem to make any difference.
It seems ffmpeg auto-detects chroma_location in input anyway so the user only needs to intervene if it happens to be incorrect? And in PAL 4:2:0 input and in .mp4 4:2:0 output it does not matter anyway? So maybe I can omit chroma_location from the commands below at least for PAL:
ffmpeg7 -i 4_3_PAL.dv -vf bwdif=1,scale=788:576,crop=768:576:10:0,setsar=sar=1/1,setparams=range=limited:color_primaries=bt470bg:color_trc=bt709:colorspace=smpte170m:chroma_location=topleft -c:v libx265 -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -profile:v main10 -timecode 00:00:00:00 -tag:v hvc1 -c:a aac -b:a 128k 4_3_PAL_dv_to_10bit_limited_5-1-6.mp4

Which among all yields deeper reds than the default with untagged colors:
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0 (Type 2)
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.601 PAL
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601

A similar command for 4:3 NTSC .dv where chroma_location in the 4:1:1 .dv might matter?
ffmpeg7 -i 4_3_NTSC.dv -vf bwdif=1,scale=648:480,crop=640:480:4:0,setsar=sar=1/1,setparams=range=limited:color_primaries=smpte170m:color_trc=bt709:colorspace=smpte170m:chroma_location=topleft -c:v libx265 -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -profile:v main10 -timecode '00:00:00;00' -tag:v hvc1 -c:a aac -b:a 128k 4_3_NTSC_dv_to_10bit_limited_6-1-6.mp4

ffmpeg4 does not seem to support setting chroma_location at least like this.
Years ago I used a similar command for PAL .dv but then to 8-bit without color attributes and range (which defaulted to limited). I considered re-encoding but it seems just adding color might losslessly work without re-encoding with a command below? (hvc1 and timecode can also be added, but of course 8-bit must be re-encoded to 10-bit). Also setting range to full/limited seems to work later but I am not sure if that really works:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -color_range 1 -color_primaries:v bt470bg -color_trc:v bt709 -colorspace:v smpte170m -timecode 00:00:00:00 -tag:v hvc1 output.mp4

